# Best method updating sandbox tables with production tables/views

Tags: sql-server, development-environment, production-environment, insert-update

Using SQL, it is taking over 4 hours every evening to pull over all the data from the twelve Production database tables or views needed for our Sandbox database. There has to be a significantly more efficient and effective manner to get this data into our Sandbox.

Currently, I'm creating a UID (Unique ID) by concatenating the views Primary Keys and system date fields.

The UID is used in two steps:

Step 1. 
`INSERT INTO Sandbox 
WHERE UID IS NULL`
and only Looking back the Last 30 Days based on the System Date 
(using Left Join the Production Table/View.UID to the Existing Sandbox Table/View.UID)

Step 2. 
`UPDATE Sandbox 
Where Production.UID = Sandbox.UID`
(using an Inner Join of the Production Table/View.UID to the Existing Sandbox Table/View.UID)

I've cut the 4 hour time down to 2 hours, but it feels like this process I've created is missing a (big) step.

How can I cut this time down? Should I put a 30 day filter on my UPDATE statement as well?

Comment: Why not put triggers on your production database tables, and on insert update, insert or update your sandbox, then you would have no need to migrate the data.

Comment: I would not use triggers to replicate an entire production system. That's a good way to introduce bottlenecks for your end users.

Comment: How much data are you moving?  It should be fairly simple to setup an ETL process for twelve tables.  Why can't you just use a truncate/full load strategy?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I'm only pulling from 15-20 tables, but the majority of those tables hold millions (not billions) of records. This is not a complete DB replication, but the truncate/full strategy takes 4+ hours, and I need this to run in an hour or two at most.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not moving billions of rows into your development environment, I would just create a simple ETL strategy to truncate the dev environment and do a full load from production.  If you don't want the full dataset, add a filter to the source queries for your ETL.  Just make sure that doesn't have any effect on the integrity of the data.

If your data is in the billions, you likely have a enterprise storage solution in place.  Many of those can handle snapshotting the data files to another location.  There are some security aspects with that approach that you'll need to consider as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that is in two parts. It may not be the best solution, but it seems to be working for the moment.

1. I can use primary keys as my UID from the production box database tables (for the most part). Updating them using a 30-90 day filter
2. The views are a bit trickier as they union two exact tables and have duplicate primary keys. So, I created my own uid concatenating multiple primary key fields and updating with a 30-90 day filter.

The previous process would take up to 4+ hours to complete. The new process runs in an hour, and seems to be working for the moment.